# Filter ListView with multiple enum

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, enums

I'm trying to filter a ListView with checkboxes filters, and applying these filters to an enum. It's working for one filter, but not for a combination. 
The enum have all the values power of two, and the `[Flags]` attribute.
Here is my code :

```
int statuses = 0;
        if ((bool)Filter1CB.IsChecked)
        {
            statuses++;
        }
        if ((bool)Filter2CB.IsChecked)
        {
            statuses += 2;
        }
        if ((bool)Filter3CB.IsChecked)
        {
            statuses += 4;
        }
        if ((bool)Filter4CB.IsChecked)
        {
            statuses += 8;
        }
Sp.Filter = item =>
            {
                return item is Sp sp && sp.CurrentStatus == (SpStatus)statuses;
            };
```

I checked, the value of statuses is 3 when filter 1 and 2 are checked, and so on. But it's not applying any filter...
Here is my enum :

```
[Flags]
    public enum SpStatus
    {
        Filter1 =   1 << 0,   
        Filter2 =   1 << 1,  
        Filter3 =   1 << 2,    
        Filter4 =   1 << 3,    

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your filter needs to test if the incoming item has a match for all the specified flags. So a logical AND is used to extract the filtering flags. Then a comparison against the filter flags ensure we are only interested in items that have all the flags set.

```
Sp.Filter = item =>
{
    Sp sp = (Sp)item;
    return (sp.CurrentStatus & (SpStatus)statuses) == (SpStatus)statuses;
};
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Same result, working for one filter, not for a combination.

Comment: Set a breakpoint in the lambda and check you have the right statuses setup from the preceding code because this lambda definitely works as intended.

Comment: What's realy strange is that the lambda seems to be totaly OK, even with the breakpoint it seems I have no error... But the debugger tells me that `(sp.CurrentStatus & (SpStatus)statuses) == (SpStatus)statuses` is false. Even if in the statuses I can see in the debugger exactly the same two statuses I've checked, and sp.CurrentStatus is one of the two...

Comment: Your answer where the good ! But you made a mistake. I had to revert the result, it's `(sp.CurrentStatus & (SpStatus)statuses) == sp.CurrentStatus;` and not `(sp.CurrentStatus & (SpStatus)statuses) == (SpStatus)statuses);`. Seems logic now !

Comment: Ah yes, well spotted.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible for you to declare your enum like this?

```
[Flags]
    public enum Status
    {
        Filter0 = 0,
        Filter1 = 1,
        Filter2 = 2,
        Filter3 = 3,
        Filter4 = 4,

    }
```

Comment: This way i can't combine enums with bitwise operations, for what I know

Answer (score 0):

Your enum name is `Status` why do you Cast it as `SpStatus`?

> sp.CurrentStatus == (SpStatus)statuses;

I would do it like:

```
CheckBox[] boxes = new CheckBox[] {Filter1CB, Filter2CB, Filter3CB, Filter4CB}
int stat = 0, pow = 1;
foreach(CheckBox c in boxes)
{   
    if(c.IsChecked)  stat += pow;
    pow *= 2;
}    
Filter = (Status)stat;
```

Comment: Sorry for the typo, it's corrected. The enum is SpStatus.

Comment: The Filter{i}CB notation is not my real code, it was for the example. In my cro it's a different name for each filter.

Comment: It's a faster way than mine to write the same code. And get the same error, tried now.

Comment: not an error, but the filter work for one checkbox, not for two (list is empty)